# How to debug "pika.exceptions.AuthenticationError: EXTERNAL" error when establishing TLS connection to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, ssl, rabbitmq, pika

I have a RabbitMQ 3.6.1 server on Ubuntu 14.04 running properly. I tried to configure an SSL listener according to [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html). No problems during the startup.

However when trying to establish a connection, I get the following error on Python/pika side (full transcript below):

```
pika.exceptions.AuthenticationError: EXTERNAL
```

What does `EXTERNAL` mean here? How to debug / get further details of the error?

---

Course of actions (to test I used a Vagrant box and a local connection):

1. RabbitMQ starts SSL Listener on port 5671 (per `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@rabbitmq-server.log`):

   ```
   started SSL Listener on [::]:5671
   ```
2. I execute the `pika.BlockingConnection` on the client side.
3. On the server side I can see an incoming connection:

   ```
   =INFO REPORT==== 17-Apr-2016::17:07:15 ===
   accepting AMQP connection <0.2788.0> (127.0.0.1:48404 -> 127.0.0.1:5671)
   ```
4. Client fails with:

   ```
   pika.exceptions.AuthenticationError: EXTERNAL
   ```
5. Server timeouts:

   ```
   =ERROR REPORT==== 17-Apr-2016::17:07:25 ===
   closing AMQP connection <0.2788.0> (127.0.0.1:48404 -> 127.0.0.1:5671):
   {handshake_timeout,frame_header}
   ```

---

Full transcript of the client side:

```
>>> import pika, ssl
>>> from pika.credentials import ExternalCredentials
>>> ssl_options = ({"ca_certs": "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/testca/cacert.pem",
...                 "certfile": "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/client/cert.pem",
...                 "keyfile": "/etc/rabbitmq/certs/client/key.pem",
...                 "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
...                 "server_side": False})
>>> host = "localhost"
>>> connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
...                  pika.ConnectionParameters(
...                      host, 5671, credentials=ExternalCredentials(),
...                      ssl=True, ssl_options=ssl_options))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 602, in poll
    self._process_fd_events(fd_event_map, write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 443, in _process_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events, write_only=write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 415, in _handle_read
    self._on_data_available(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1347, in _on_data_available
    self._process_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1414, in _process_frame
    if self._process_callbacks(frame_value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1384, in _process_callbacks
    frame_value)  # Args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 60, in wrapper
    return function(*tuple(args), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 236, in process
    callback(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1298, in _on_connection_start
    self._send_connection_start_ok(*self._get_credentials(method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1077, in _get_credentials
    raise exceptions.AuthenticationError(self.params.credentials.TYPE)
pika.exceptions.AuthenticationError: EXTERNAL
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python / pika code in the question is correct.

The error:

> pika.exceptions.AuthenticationError: EXTERNAL

is reported when client certificate authorisation is not enabled on the RabbitMQ server side. The word `EXTERNAL` in the error refers to the authentication mechanism as [described here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_1/README.md).

To enable:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl
```

Comment: you also need to make sure that the rabbit.config allows EXTERNAL auth. Mine was looking like this when I came here in search for clues:
`{auth_mechanisms, ['PLAIN', 'AMQPLAIN']},`
notice: EXTERNAL not mentioned!

Comment: @Chris Thanks for valuable input.

Comment: @techraf  Any chance I can have a look at the source code? I cannot seem to get it to work. I get an error: "TypeError: ssl_options must be None or SSLOptions but got..."